# Mono WCF Problems with IClientChannel

Tags: wcf, mono

I'm new to mono but have been asked to look into running an existing .NET client application of ours using mono for Linux, Android and/or MacOS.

The server/client uses WCF duplex communication with NetTcpBinding. I've created a much trimmed down version of the client to try to analyze which of the fundamentals of the connection to the server will work in mono (I'm running mono v2.10.8).

The first problem I had was that a cast to IClientChannel. The factory.CreateChannel result on the client side was giving an InvalidCastException. But I managed to get around this by creating a helper interface that implements the service contract and IClientChannel

`public interface IMySessionChannel : IMySession, IClientChannel {}`

... and using this in my ChannelFactory

`_factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IMySessionChannel>(....)`

But I'm still having a bit of a problem. I've added event handlers for the Closing, Closed and Faulted events of IClientChannel which write a message to screen on the client side when receiving the events.

Everything works fine on Windows, but when running the client in mono (still on the windows machine just running the mono command prompt) and shutting down the server, the events don't seem to come through to the client.

Am I missing something in this? Is there a general issue with IClientChannel interface in mono? The calls to the server are working as are the callbacks, but I'm just having some issue with IClientChannel.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There was [bug #4511](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4511) related to `DuplexChannelFactory` in Mono, which prevented the channel from being cast to `IClientChannel`.  I fixed that last week, but it's possible that there are other problems.

If you're still having problems, could you please file a bug report with a test case?